# Add more information to WP_DEBUG

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging, logging

As my Wordpress site is on production, I've set wp_config.php as followed:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

Is there a chance, that I can append any information to the log, p.e. the user ID or page slug? Couldn't find any debug filters on google.

**SOLUTION**

I've figured it out by creating my own error handler which looks as followed:

```
set_error_handler('custom_error_log');
function custom_error_log ($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    global $post, $current_user;
    //Message
        /*Is there a function to get rid of this switch statement?*/
    switch ($errno) {
        case 2:
            $type = "WARNING";
            break;
        case 8:
            $type = "NOTICE";
            break;
        case 256:
            $type = "FATAL ERROR";
            break;
        case 512:
            $type = "USER_WARNING";
            break;
        case 1024:
            $type = "USER_NOTICE";
            break;
        default:
            $type = "[$errno]";
    }
    $message = "$errstr";

    //Location
        $location = str_replace(get_template_directory().'/','',$errfile);

    //Cause
    if ($current_user->ID) {
        $user = "User {$current_user->ID}";
    } else {
        $user = "Guest";
    }
    $cause ="$user on '{$post->post_title}'";

    //Log
    $log = "$type\n  $message | $location($errline) | $cause";
    error_log($log);

    //Post Log to wherever else you want to, p.e. Slack.
}
```

Comment: Honestly, I don't know, it only shows the PHP error (and I would love to watch this thread). 
The only way I know how to do this kind of info is to write your own debugger which will track what you need (or I do this with my own plugins communicating with APIs etc.).

Comment: I misread your question, deleted my answer.

Comment: no there isn't. You need to implement yourself using string functions http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php